# Seeking proof that the greedy algorithm is in fact the most optimal algorithm to construct graph with maximum variance in its degree distribution.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, network, extremal-graph-theory

User inputs: number of nodes (n) and number of links (k).

Objective: create an undirected (n,k) graph without multi-edges and without self loops that exhibits the maximum standard deviation in its degree distribution. In other words, create a graph in which the nodes have degrees with the highest variance.

My greedy algorithm: assign the first node n-1 (maximum possible number) links. Assign the second node n-2 links. Assigned the third node n-3 links... And so on. Till the total number of links in the graph reaches k.

Seeking help on: I'm unable to prove that this greedy algorithm guarantees the maximum standard deviation in the degree distribution of the graph.

Comment: Do you require the graph to be connected?

Comment: No, some nodes can be unconnected.

Comment: Then for $n=5, k=6$, degrees $\{3,3,3,3,0\}$ has higher variance than $\{4,3,2,2,1\}$

Comment: I agree. My bad! Is there an algorithm or can you suggest an algorithm that provides me the degree distribution that has the highest variance?

Comment: @DanielMathias, any help with my previous comment?

Comment: I think your greedy algorithm is good, but you will need to also consider graphs with one or more isolated nodes. For the purpose of checking any other methods you might try, I have used some rather inefficient brute-force code to determine maximum variance for small numbers of nodes: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/5WzGAnQX)

Comment: Updated list: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/eWGKcthi) Now shows all graphs with maximum variance. You might notice the complementary nature of graphs with few edges compared to graphs with many edges. I hope this helps.

Comment: This helps! Looks like there isn't a well-established algorithm (that I could find) for generating the required. In any case, I will see if I can improve my algorithm to get as close to the optima (variance maxima degree distribution) as possible, though I cannot think of a strategy yet. Thanks, Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The following has been confirmed, via code, for all $k\le n\le 30$. A proof of this claim is requested by Aman Kabra for an acceptable answer.

Your greedy algorithm is optimal, but you need to check two cases. The first case is $f(n,k)$ and the second case is $f(n,c-k)$, where $c=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, the number of edges in a complete graph on $n$ vertices. The complement of the graph from the second case has $k$ edges, and one or both of these cases will provide a graph of maximal variance.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. This seems to give the correct answer. 

For the sake of completion of this thread, what is the "proof" behind your algorithm:

$\max{\operatorname{var}(G(n,k)), G'(n,k))}$?

Comment: I tried drawing up a proof myself for why what Daniel said is the optimal algorithm to arrive at the degree distribution with the highest variance. I have been unsuccessful thus far. Can I be pointed toward some resources that I can look into?

Comment: @AmanKabra I have confirmed this for all $k\le n\le 30$ via code, but I am unable to provide a formal proof.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will figure it out and post the proof here if I'm successful.